# search result in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a program that allows the user to do a search in the warehouse. The result is returned in a JTable.

So far everything is good. When I attempt to do a second search, the old table is still showing.

#### Image:

[image]

#### Code:

```
public void panelTable(){
    panelTable= new JPanel();
    panelTable.setSize(400, 80);
    panelTable.setOpaque(true);
    panelTab =  new JTable();
    modele  = new DefaultTableModel();
}

public void creerJTable(List<Pneu> liste){
    String[] head= {"A", "B", "C"};
    Object[][] data = null;
    
    data = new Object[liste.size()][3];
    Iterator<Pneu> it = liste.iterator();
    int index = 0;
    
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Pneu unPneu = it.next();
        data[index][0] = unPneu.descrip();
        data[index][1] = unPneu.width();
        data[index][2] = unPneu.height();
        index++;
    }

    modele.setDataVector(data, head);
    
    panelTab.setModel(modele);
    
    panelTab.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    panelTab.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    panelTab.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 80));
    panelTab.setModel(modeleColonnesNoEdit(data, entete));

    panelTab.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);
    panelTab.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(250);
    panelTab.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
    panelTab.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(50);
    panelTab.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
    panelTab.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(50);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panelTab);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 60));

    panelTable.add(scrollPane);
}
```

When clicking on the search button,  you are taken to the class Listener which verifies that the button search was clicked. Once that is done, you have this code:

frame.creerJTable(liste);

This line of code, takes the list created from that search and calls the method creerJTable(List liste) that is shown in the above code.

Here's the code for the modeleColonnesNoEdit()

```
private DefaultTableModel modeleColonnesNoEdit(Object[][] data, String[] head) {
        
    return new DefaultTableModel(data, head)
    {
        
        boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] { false, false, false};

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return columnEditables[column];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: @manestsus thank you for the edit. Will you be able to answer the question?

Comment: Will you provide your search event code , so that we can understand the problem

Comment: @Alok I added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be re-adding a JScrollPane or adding any new components to the GUI in the search. Instead, take the original JTable, simply change its TableModel, and that's it, do nothing more.